# Matlab: Empty value returned from a getter function

Tags: matlab, function, getter, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

Let's say I have two classes, i.e. A and B, and need to return a value in class B to A. Hence, I have created a getter function in the following form:

```
function y = getValue(obj)
    y = obj.value;
end
```

In class A, therefore, I try to retrieve the value by instantiating class B and calling the getter method in the following fashion:

```
obj.bVar = B(); % Instantiate class B and assign to variable 'bVar' in class A

obj.aVar = obj.bVar.getValue(); % Call the getter function
```

Furthermore, I would expect the 'aVar' variable to have a value assigned to it, which is the value of whatever was assigned to 'bVar'. However, when using the 'disp()' method to display the contents of 'aVar' it is empty.

Do you know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You are returning the `value` property of the object in the getter function, not the object itself.  Is the `obj.value` assigned a valid value or is it empty?

Comment: Are these value classes or handle classes? Can you post the exact sequence of commands you're using to construct the classes, assign the `aVar`, and display it?

Comment: And the classdef code itself?